# Show/Hide toolbar on scrolling recycler view inside a Fragment Framelayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-recyclerview, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to achieve hiding & showing of `Toolbar` on scrolling `RecyclerView` using **Android Design Support Library**.

Similar to this [Material Design Scrolling Technique](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsR1lZQUxtWFRFMEU/patterns-scrolling-techniques_standard_appbar_xhdpi_004.webm)

But unfortunately the `Toolbar` is not getting hide or shown.

---

Here's the code:
**Main Activity Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/base_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Fragment shown from "Framelayout"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:id="@+id/songs_list" />
```

**Build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

I have tried adding `RecyclerView` import in gradle but it then too didn't work

Comment: Could you post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: What are your `buildToolsVersion`?

Comment: @Arkadiy
It is:
`buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

Comment: I know you have tried that already, but nevertheless, please add `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'` line in your `build.gradle` file. I've just tried to compile working project without it and it couldn't even find `RecyclerView` class.

Comment: @Arkadly I guess some of my dependency uses Recycler View dependency that's why I didn't get any error using that class. I'll add that import statement & let you know in sometime.

Comment: I've just tried your layout and it is working fine for me - toobar collapses on scroll correctly. I'm not really sure what else might be the issue

Comment: @Arkadiy I created sample it worked over there, but didn't in required app.

Comment: Then probably all teh related code required (layout as well as initialization of toolbar/recyclerview in activity/fragment). Could you post add it here or host the project on github, for example?

Comment: @Arkadiy it suddenly started to work. I'll try to find what I did exactly.

Comment: Did you find a solution? :)

Comment: @8m47x
I don't remember exactly if I solved or not. But I guess it got solved on use of `RecyclerView`